# returning a structure without exposing it

Tags: c++

I have a structure in my program

```
struct secret_structure{
             string a;
             string  b;
             void *c;
};
```

I have a list of such structures

```
std::map<string name, secret_structure> my_map
```

I have to write a function that returns the structure by mapping it with the name.

```
get_from_map(string name, secret_structure * struct) //Kind of function
```

I have following options:

1. Pass a pointer of a secret_structure in the get_from_map function. The get_from_map populates the structure. I don't want to do this because the structure will be exposed.
2. I can have different functions for returning different values from the structure. Here the structure will not be exposed but does not look clean.

Can you help me with any other option such that the structure itself is not exposed.

Comment: Why don't you want to expose the structure?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just make the data members of `secret_structure` _private_? And then have accessor functions for those parts you want to expose?

Comment: Even if it were possible, what is the caller supposed to do with this unexposed structure?

Comment: You may want to read about the [pimpl idiom](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom).

Comment: @juanchopanza: It makes a tiny bit of sense if you want to treat the pointers as handles to some opaque structure.  C does something similar with `FILE`.  Not sure i like the idea for C++, where encapsulation is built into the language...but eh.  It's not without precedent...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of passing a structure you could pass an handle that contains a pointer to the real object:

```
// public_interface.h

struct MySecretStruct; // I don't want to publish what's inside

struct WhatYouCanSee
{
    MySecretStruct *msp; // The "P"ointer to "IMPLE"mentation

    WhatYouCanSee(int a, double b);
    ~WhatYouCanSee();
    WhatYouCanSee& operator=(const WhatYouCanSee&);
    WhatYouCanSee(const WhatYouCanSee&);

    void method1();
    void method2(int x);
};
```

The methods will be just wrappers to calls to methods of the real object.

Comment: +1 - an important technique.  Worth considering making it non-copyable though, as the choice of semantics would be pretty arbitrary and potentially confusing. (e.g. should your `operator=(const WhatYouCanSee&)` copy data between `MySecretStructs`, or just make `msp` address the same `MySecretStruct`?)

Comment: @TonyD: As with a regular (non-pimpled) object you can decide what to do for assignment and copy construction. One solution I found often useful is to have the back instance reference counted so that the front object can be copied (and you can place it in standard containers) but the real instance is not copied.

Comment: Oh - I see you just edited the 'The "Pointer" to "IMPLE"mentation' into your answer.  I'd actually thought you were suggesting a custom proxy interface (without ownership) for the specific access needed by the code calling the lookup.  `pImpl` implies *all* client code using `WhatYouCanSee`s (and therefore indirection, ownership, extra heap usage, and a potentially fatter interface).  Either may suit - devil's in the details.

Answer (score 7):

What you want is the pimpl idiom.

[Pimple Idiom](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom)

Basically you declare a class that has an interface to the secret structure and holds a pointer to an instance of the secret structure. You can forward declare the struct without specifying implementation details. Then in the CPP file you access the secret structure. This can be provided in a header/binary format if you are providing it to 3rd parties.

Answer (score 1):

Then return in json or xml or some other format.

or ASN.1 may be more compact

Comment: -1 There's nothing in the question to suggest a run-time parsed format is desirable, while it introduces a significant new surface for run-time errors, slows things down, and makes it harder to use the results.  Notes: one of the freedoms this allows - returning results that aren't in 1:1 correspondence with `secret_structure` fields - is better handled with a separate `struct`; another aspect is ownership, but lookup of a struct in a `map` could return it by `const` reference, by value, by `shared_ptr`, `weak_ptr` or `unique_ptr`... no benefit there in other formats either.

Comment: @TonyD Your comment sounds more like an good answer to the original question ? Why are you commenting on my comment?

Comment: "Why are you commenting on my comment?" - you've entered above an "answer"; comments get listed directly under the question. People are implicitly invited to vote and comment on answers - that's the primary concept for this website, and how the best answers "float" to the top of the page. 6502's answer recommends the same intermediate `struct` approach I mention - no point in my adding a duplicate answer. My comment was basically to point out that the by-value benefits from your answer are available without the undesirable move to an intermediate data format.

Comment: @TonyD ok , Fair enough

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that (at least, not with conventional C++), and I cannot think a good reason for which you should do that. If your internal struct is not the way you want to publish your information, find a suitable way/data type and define a conversion.